# How to exit EventHandler after event.consume()?

Tags: java, events, exit

My code is:

```
private EventHandler<KeyEvent> fieldChangeListener(final Integer max_Lengh, final Boolean fullTrimming) {
    return new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            TextField field = (TextField) event.getSource();
            String text = field.getText();
            int lastCharIndex = 0;

            if (field.getText().length() > 0) {
                lastCharIndex = field.getText().length() - 1;
            }

            if (field.getText().length() >= max_Lengh) {
                System.out.println("Exit 1");
                event.consume();
            }

            if (fullTrimming) {
                if (event.getCharacter().matches("\\s")) {
                    System.out.println("Exit 2");
                    event.consume();
                }
            } else {
                if (field.getText().length() == 0 && event.getCharacter().matches("\\s")) {
                    System.out.println("Exit 3");
                    event.consume();
                } else if (field.getText().substring(lastCharIndex).equals(" ")
                        && event.getCharacter().matches("\\s")) {
                    System.out.println("Exit 4");
                    event.consume();
                }
            }
            Region icon = (Region) ((StackPane)field.getParent()).getChildren().get(1);
            text = text+event.getCharacter();
            System.out.println("Char: " + text);
```

Even after event is getting consumed, code continues to execute. So as a result I can get output like:

```
Exit 1
Exit 4
Char: jk i okkl
```

But I want to exit `EventHandler` as soon as `event.consumed()` is getting triggered. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a few `return` statements:

```
        if (field.getText().length() >= max_Lengh) {
            System.out.println("Exit 1");
            event.consume();
            return;
        }

        if (fullTrimming) {
            if (event.getCharacter().matches("\\s")) {
                System.out.println("Exit 2");
                event.consume();
                return;
            }
        } else {
            ...
        }
        ...
```

Then you might want to refactor this method a little. usually we should aim for only one `return` statements.

#### Update

Here is the code with **all** the necessary `return`-s:

```
public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            TextField field = (TextField) event.getSource();
            String text = field.getText();
            int lastCharIndex = 0;

            if (field.getText().length() > 0) {
                lastCharIndex = field.getText().length() - 1;
            }

            if (field.getText().length() >= max_Lengh) {
                System.out.println("Exit 1");
                event.consume();
                return;
            }

            if (fullTrimming) {
                if (event.getCharacter().matches("\\s")) {
                    System.out.println("Exit 2");
                    event.consume();
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                if (field.getText().length() == 0 && event.getCharacter().matches("\\s")) {
                    System.out.println("Exit 3");
                    event.consume();
                    return;
                } else if (field.getText().substring(lastCharIndex).equals(" ")
                        && event.getCharacter().matches("\\s")) {
                    System.out.println("Exit 4");
                    event.consume();
                    return;
            }
        }
        Region icon = (Region) ((StackPane)field.getParent()).getChildren().get(1);
        text = text+event.getCharacter();
        System.out.println("Char: " + text);

        return;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason behind that?

Comment: *Usually* that's easier to understand. There are a few exceptions though. E.g. it's okay to have some sort of null-checking in the beginning of the method and return with a default value for not-so-sensible input. [Clean Code](https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) is a great book - but use it judiciously.

Comment: Just tested it out, code after `if` statement with `return` still continuous executing

Comment: Well, I didn't add all the necessary `return`-s. Now you can see them all after the **Update** part.

Comment: I didn't copy paste it, just added `return`s after each `event.consume()`, but I still got in console `Char: text`

Comment: ok, found it mistake was in my code, so one part with return wasn't called. Works fine now)